# Sort CSV comparing only first element in each row

Tags: c#, .net, csv, sorting

How do you sort comma separated values in a file by comparing only first element in each row?

Comment: What do you have so far? Is there a specific part of the problem you're having problems with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Read the file line by line
- Split the lines at the commas
- Sort
- Write back to file

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile).OrderBy(line => line.Split(",")[0])
```

Just note that this assumes your input is always valid. You would have to add your own error checking (empty rows, empty files, etc)

Comment: Please do not post code for obvious homework questions. That's not helpful. Rather point in the right direction.

Comment: You're right, I could have taken either the Socratic or the Zen Master approach, but this was easier ;)

Comment: +1 because now that the Homework tag is obsolete, and this is a question and answer site, this is the best answer.